# Adding some background information to a layer

Tags: python, qgis-plugins

I have 2 Python Qgis plugins. The first plugin is creating a QgsVectorLayer via the ogr dataprovider. The second plugin is offering some services on the features in the layer.

I need to pass some additional information (a single string) which is not in the file that ogr reads to the second plugin. What's the best /easiest way to attach it to the layer so the second plugin can easily extract it?

Answer (score 2):

If it's just one additional information for each layer, maybe you could pass it through the metadata. 
In other case, if there are different informations for each feature in the layer you could join an attribute table.

Comment: Thanks, the metadata idea sounds promising. However, can you give me more details on how to do that. It seems easy to query metadata on a layer, but I can't seem to find a method to set it?

Comment: I found this: http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Layer-level-metadata-td4120449.html. This would work in my case but remains unsatisfactory for the reasons mentioned in the link.